# Navbar funciona en pagina A pero no en B, y son casi copias

Tags: html, css, dropdown

Estoy tratando de entender por que mi navbar dropdown no funciona en algunas páginas de mi sitio.

Este es el navbar, el cual es una sección la cual integro en el resto de páginas.
Este al final tiene un dropdown, que por alguna razon, en la página de más abajo, no funciona.

Y más abajo dejo la página donde no funciona, lo que no entiendo, es por que no funciona.

Segun yo tendria que ver con los links que se mandan a llamar, pero no veo que cometa un problema para identificarlo.

```
NAVBAR.PHP

<div class="superTop">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <p style="font-weight:500;"> DATOS DE CONTACTO </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION["superMod"])){
        echo "<div>Ustéd ha iniciado sesión como ".$_SESSION["superMod"]."</div>";
    }
?>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-custom">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="direccionSitio.cl" style="font-weight: bolder; color: whitesmoke">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="direccionSitio.cl">Inicio<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="direccionSitio.cl">Nosotros</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="direccionSitio.cl">Servicios</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="direccionSitio.cl">Contacto</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <?php
            if (!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true) {
                $url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
                if (!$url == 'direccionSitio.cl') { ?>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="direccionSitio.cl">Iniciar sesión</a>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <!-- <a class="dropdown-item" href="direccionSitio.cl">Cambiar Contraseña</a> -->
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="direccionSitio.cl">Cerrar Sesión</a>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </li>
    </div>
</nav>
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="gb18030">
    <title>Resumen Histórico</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.23/af-2.3.5/b-1.6.5/b-colvis-1.6.5/b-flash-1.6.5/b-html5-1.6.5/b-print-1.6.5/cr-1.5.3/fc-3.3.2/fh-3.1.8/kt-2.6.1/r-2.2.7/rg-1.1.2/rr-1.2.7/sc-2.0.3/sb-1.0.1/sp-1.2.2/sl-1.3.1/datatables.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.23/af-2.3.5/b-1.6.5/b-colvis-1.6.5/b-flash-1.6.5/b-html5-1.6.5/b-print-1.6.5/cr-1.5.3/fc-3.3.2/fh-3.1.8/kt-2.6.1/r-2.2.7/rg-1.1.2/rr-1.2.7/sc-2.0.3/sb-1.0.1/sp-1.2.2/sl-1.3.1/datatables.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <script>
        if (window.history.replaceState) {
            window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.href);
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                closeText: 'Cerrar',
                prevText: '<Ant',
                nextText: 'Sig>',
                currentText: 'Hoy',
                monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
                monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
                dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
                dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mié', 'Juv', 'Vie', 'Sáb'],
                dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sá'],
                weekHeader: 'Sm',
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                firstDay: 1,
                isRTL: false,
                showMonthAfterYear: false,
                yearSuffix: '',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
            }) /*.datepicker("setDate", new Date())*/ ;
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <?php require_once("navbar.php"); ?>
    <!-- <div id="preloader" class="preloader"></div>
    <div class="black-screen"></div> -->
    <div class="container">
        [...contenido pagina...]
    </div>
    <?php require_once("footer.php"); ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#table_content').DataTable({
                dom: 'lBfrtip',
                buttons: {
                    buttons: [{
                        extend: 'excel',
                        className: 'btn btn-success',
                        text: 'Descargar como Excel'
                    }]
                },
                "scrollY": "40vh",
                "ordering": true,
                "order": [
                    [2, "asc"]
                ],
                "paging": false,
                "info": true,
                "language": {
                    "decimal": ",",
                    "thousands": ".",
                    "emptyTable": "No hay datos disponibles en la tabla",
                    "info": "Mostrando _START_-_END_ de _TOTAL_ entradas",
                    "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0-0 de 0 entradas",
                    "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de un total de _MAX_ entradas)",
                    "infoPostFix": "",
                    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ entradas",
                    "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                    "processing": "Procesando...",
                    "search": "Buscar:",
                    "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron registros para la b煤squeda",
                    "paginate": {
                        "first": "Primero",
                        "last": "脷ltimo",
                        "next": "Siguiente",
                        "previous": "Anterior"
                    },
                    "aria": {
                        "sortAscending": ": activate to sort column ascending",
                        "sortDescending": ": activate to sort column descending"
                    }
                },
                "autoWidth": true
            });
        });
        $(function() {
            $('.preloader, .black-screen').fadeOut(1000);
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontré una solución, pero no explica por que antes algunas funcionan y otras no.

A las que fallaban les agregué lo siguiente al final de la página:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Luego de agregar el js de bootstrap, todo funciona.
Pero como dije, en las páginas que SI funcionaba, este código no existe, y el dropdown funciona bien.